# How to substring a pattern in batch script and then print next characters

Tags: batch-file

I am looking for substr function in batch script so that script will search for any patter in string and then chop that particular string and set in a variable. Eg To search a string starts with USI and then print next 10 character after it and then set it in a new variable. to achieve the same i am using below code :

```
for /f "delims=" %%A in ('
    grep "USI" "text.log" 
    ^| awk "{print substr($17,0,10)}"
') do set "var=%%A"
```

**Edit**

From above code I am just fetching using the field number, but here I want to substring using the particular search like in java we have as below. Please let me know any confusion in it.

```
String s = "Monday";
if(s.subString(0,3).equals("Mon"){
} 
String s2 = new String(s.subString(0,3)); 
String s3 = s.subString(0,3);
```

Comment: So you already have code that does what you want, but now you want different code that does the same thing? Am I reading that correctly?

Comment: Yes , From above code I am just fetching using the field number, but here I want to substring using the particular search like in java we have as below. Please let me know any confusion in it.

String s = "Monday";
if(s.subString(0,3).equals("Mon"){}
String s2 = new String(s.subString(0,3));
String s3 = s.subString(0,3);

Comment: Please don't post code snippets in comments as it becomes a bit unreadable; [edit] your question instead. For the present, I did it for you (thus was it written). [Edit] if necessary